# How best to iron out disk I/O lag cause?

Tags: linux, partitioning, fedora, disk-encryption, io

Running luksCrypt (which I know causes some lag esp. with my -c serpent-xts-plain64 -s 512 -h whirlpool setup) but as of late lag has become very much more noticeable.   I use xfs and  lvm on this Fedora install..  Smartmontools comes back clean and not seeing major spikes in read/write activity except when expected (like saving a dl'd file to disk from /tmp) but this is happening randomly..  Ideas for finding and possibly mitigating highly appreciated.